# I want to get a big \subset

Tags: symbols

I want to get a big `\subset`,  but when I use `\bigsubset`, (just like `\bigcup`), it shows wrong. So what is the correct command?

Comment: Is `\mathlarger{\subset}` enough?  (\mathlarger is defined by package `relsize`).

Comment: What would be your usecase for a large version of the symbol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set builder notation command, adjusting mid bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425859/set-builder-notation-command-adjusting-mid-bar)

Answer (score 9):

The macro `\bigsubset` defined in the following solution uses (a) the `\scalebox` macro of the `graphicx` package to up-size the `\subset` symbol and (b) the TeX-primitive `\vcenter` directive to keep the enlarged `\subset` symbols centered on the math axis. It also employs a `\mathrel` directive to inform LaTeX that the enlarged symbol should be treated as a "relational" symbol.

The default scaling factor is `1.2`; the default is easily overridden.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox macro
\newcommand\bigsubset[1][1.19]{%
   \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\subset$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\subset B$, $A\bigsubset B$, $A\bigsubset[1.44]B$, $A\bigsubset[1.7]B$, $A\bigsubset[2]B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I had to make "large operators" from regular size (10pt) CM symbols, I found that the 14pt size (actually 14.4pt) was closest to the existing large CM operators.  So scaling 1.5 is a tiny bit large.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks! I've updated my answer; it now shows the result of scaling by 1.44.

Answer (score 5):

Using the basic commands to increase a text, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\HUGE`, you can obtain different sizes of the command `\subset`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$A\mbox{\large$\subset$}B$

$A\mbox{\Large$\subset$}B$

$A\mbox{\LARGE$\subset$}B$

$A\mbox{\huge$\subset$}B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: A subset of any size should be aligned vertically on the math axis.  The enlarged forms here all have their bottom at the same (original) position.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hi, you mean on the x-axis, for example? I try to put them on the same axis.

Comment: No, not the x-axis.  The math axis is vertical, the vertical midpoint of a (for example) parenthesis.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have not understood, your request. Peraphs must I to align the sequence using align? Or as the delete answer?

Comment: Put this another way.  The math axis is the vertical midpoint between the (potentially) tallest character in a line and the longest descender (e.g.. the tail of a "y").  The minus sign is positioned along the math axis.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Peraphs I have understood. If I cut every symbol with a straight veritcal line I have not into my code the same pieces (left and right). Is it correct?

Comment: Instead of cutting the symbol in half vertically, place it next to a minus sign.  Half should be above, and half below the minus sign.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Please see the code in my answer. It uses `\vcenter` to vertically center the symbol on the math axis. Aside: The math axis is where the horizontal bars of "plus" and "minus" symbols are placed. `=` symbols are centered vertically on the math axis as well.

Comment: @Mico Hi, thank you very very much for your reply. I have seen your excellent code, but I'm able to create the same thing in this moment :-(. Sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano - No rush! Incidentally, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414613/5001) illustrates the position of the math axis graphically.